# Spring Request Scoped Beans initialized by Factory

Tags: spring

I am having a problem creating request scoped beans within a sample app I am trying. The code I am using is as follows

Site.java

```
public interface Site {
    int getId();
    String getCode();
    String getName();
}
```

SiteImpl.java

```
public class SiteImpl implements Site {
    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public SiteImpl(int id, String name, String code) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And finally SiteFactory.java

```
@Service
public class SiteFactory implements FactoryBean<SiteImpl> {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest currentRequest;

    @Override
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public SiteImpl getObject() throws Exception {
        SiteImpl site = null;
        if (currentRequest != null) {
            site = new SiteImpl(1, currentRequest.getServerName(), currentRequest.getServerName());
        }
        return site;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return SiteImpl.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error

> Cannot create scoped proxy for bean 'scopedTarget.getObject': Target
>   type could not be determined at the time of proxy creation.

Any pointers towards what I am doing wrong.

I tried setting the @Component and @Scoped annotations on the SiteImpl, but then the factory is not being called to initialize it

I also tried removing the @Scope, @Component and @Bean annotations, and instead depend on the XML configuration

```
<bean id="site" factory-bean="siteFactory" scope="request">  
   <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
</bean>
```

And I still get the same error message.

Comment: Post the full stack trace. First thing you are mixing annotations and a spring marker interface both are processed differently and basically that is trouble waiting to happen. Try removing the `FactoryBean` interface. Also instead of injecting the `HttpServletRequest` (that will only happen once or not at all) move it as a parameter to the `getObject` method (after removing the interface).

Comment: You can inject (Autowire) HttpServleRequest only into beans that are itself of scope REQUEST. Workarround: `currentRequest =
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();`

Comment: @M.Deinum Your solution worked for me. Could you post it as an answer so i can vote on it ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems

1. You are implementing `FactoryBean` and are adding annotations, basically mixing strategies which is (generally speaking) not a good idea
2. Injecting `HttpServletRequest` into a singleton object.

To fix these problems remove the `FactoryBean` interface which will give precedence to your `@Bean` annotated method. You can now also remove the `isSingleton` and `getObjectType` methods as those aren't needed.

The second problem is by simply removing the `@Autowired` attribute and simply add it as a method parameter to your `getObject` method.